# Safest way to modify .pyc compilation/loading workflow?

Tags: python, python-import, pyc

I'm working on [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy), and one of the things the project does is hook into the Python import system via PEP302 import hooks. However, one thing that I have not done (and would like to do) is to have MacroPy save imported code into `.pyc` files, just like normal imports, and use the `.pyc` files in preference to the `.py` file if the timestamps match up.

Currently, I have code that looks like this:

```
def export_transformed(self, code, tree, module_name, file_name):
    f = open(file_name + suffix , 'wb')
    f.write('\0\0\0\0')
    timestamp = long(os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_mtime)
    wr_long(f, timestamp)
    marshal.dump(code, f)
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0, 0)
    f.write(imp.get_magic())

def find(self, file, pathname, description, module_name, package_path):

    try:
        f = open(file.name + suffix, 'rb')
        x = imp.load_compiled(module_name, pathname + suffix, f)
        return x
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

This is basically copied and pasted from the [py_compile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/py_compile.html) module and modified to work with in-memory files instead of disk.

I do not like this copy&pasting because it's fragile: it doesn't work with `sys.dont_write_bytecode` and won't work with python3's `pycache`, for example. I could fix these manually to emulate the behavior, but what i'm really looking for is a way to manually call a function:

```
try_load_pyc(name, timestamp)
save_pyc(name, code)
```

and have that hook into the normal `.pyc` save/load workflow (which already respects all the pyc-related toggles, env-variables, etc.) rather than re-implementing all the behavior myself, rather than tediously re-implementing all the behavior myself.

I've googled around and haven't come up with much. Is such functionality exposed in Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, or are there third party modules that can do this for me?